# Deciding whether or not to pass an argument to a method in a using statement

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

I use the Neo4J .NET driver to get some data from a Neo4J database. I need to create a session in a `using` block, however, if I am working on a specific version of database, I need to also pass one argument to a method in the `using` block. Here is code without argument:

```
using (var conn = GraphDatabase.Driver(connectionString, AuthTokens.Basic(user, pass)).Session())
{
    // ...some logic...
}
```

And with argument:

```
using (var conn = GraphDatabase.Driver(connectionString, AuthTokens.Basic(user, pass)).Session(SessionConfigBuilder.ForDatabase(db)))
{
    // ...some logic...
}
```

I need to call one of mentioned `using` blocks in a method depending on the version passed as an argument. I am wondering how I can solve this problem? Create a custom object which returns a session, put the logic in a private method and create two ifs with either of `using` in each of them?

Comment: I don't really use neo4j but based on [the source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver/blob/3b3abc065c4eca4adffe4b2d3dd724ba3f174879/Neo4j.Driver/Neo4j.Driver.Simple/DriverExtensions.cs#L37), you could just do `var action = specificVersion ? SessionConfigBuilder.ForDatabase(db) : null;`, then you can pass `action` to `.Session()`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see any _constructor_ in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create two `using` blocks. According to [the source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver/blob/3b3abc065c4eca4adffe4b2d3dd724ba3f174879/Neo4j.Driver/Neo4j.Driver.Simple/DriverExtensions.cs#L37), the `.Session()` overload that does not take any arguments, simply calls the other overload passing `null` to it. You could simply do the same.

Create an object of type `Action<SessionConfigBuilder>` whose value is determined by the version and then pass it to the `.Session()` method. It should look something like the following:

```
var action = specificVersion ? SessionConfigBuilder.ForDatabase(db) : null;

using (var conn = GraphDatabase.Driver(connectionString, AuthTokens.Basic(user, pass))
                               .Session(action))
{

}
```